# How to convert string representation of list in pandas series to a numpy array?

Tags: pandas, numpy

now :

```
inputs.values[:2]
Out[12]: array(['[24,28]', '[8,15,9]'], dtype=object)
```

i want to get numpy 2D array   like this

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

how to transform ?

Comment: `inputs.tolist()` may be more useful. An object array does do anything for you.  Simply `eval` each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval()` and `tolist()` as below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import ast
import numpy as np

inputs = pd.Series(['[11, 21, 8]', '[18, 65, 108]'])
converted_inputs=np.array([ast.literal_eval(row) for row in inputs.tolist()])
print("converted_inputs=\n",converted_inputs)
```

The output is:

```
converted_inputs=
 [[ 11  21   8]
 [ 18  65 108]]
```